# Is it good to use a single object (player, manger, etc) as state in Composable for listener?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is for avoid writing multiple states in composable.

Here's an example. the manager

```
val manager by remember { mutableStateOf(downloadManager, neverEqualPolicy())}
```

manager contains the info we want to show in UI. `manager` has a listener:

```
DisposableEffect(true) {

    val listener = object : DownloadManager.Listener {
        override fun onDownloadChanged(downloadManager: DownloadManager, download: Download) {
            manager = downloadManager
        }

        override fun onDownloadsPausedChanged(downloadManager: DownloadManager, downloadsPaused: Boolean) {
            manager = downloadManager
        }

        override fun onDownloadRemoved(downloadManager: DownloadManager, download: Download) {
            manager = downloadManager
        }
    }

    manager.addListener(listener)
    onDispose { manager.removeListener(listener) }
}
```

And render

```
LazyColumn {
    itemsIndexed(manager.currentDownloads){index, item ->
        ListItem(headlineContent = { Text("${item.percentDownloaded}") })
    }
}
```

So every time there's an event, the manager state will be updated and then trigger the rerendering. But I want to know is this a suitable way to update UI or I have to bind every state in listener for updating UI? In that case is there any better way to update the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the `DownloadManager` instance is always the same and is used to manage the downloads, *as well* as providing a list of downloads for display. Compose works best, though, if this is separated. That's called [Unidirectional data flow](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture#udf).

The goal is to have an object that contains the state (the list of downloads) that gets passed down from the view model through the compose hierarchy to where it should be displayed, in this case the `LazyColumn`. This object would be a simple data class with nothing more, especially without any callbacks:

```
data class DownloadsUiState(
    val downloads: List<Download>,
)
```

(assuming `Download` is a simple data class as well)

The view model will also provide some functions to manage the downloads. Possible candidates would be:

```
fun addDownload(...)
fun pauseDownload(...)
fun resumeDownload(...)
fun cancelDownload(...)
fun pauseAllDownloads()
fun resumeAllDownloads()
```

They have no return value and can be used as *fire-and-forget*. Your Compose code will never see a `DownloadManager` instance. All it sees is a **state** object that gets passed down, and there are some callbacks that are used to push **events** back up.

Now the UI is free of the responsibility to handle a `DownloadManager` instance and doesn't need to know what should happen when one of the `Listener`'s callbacks is fired. All of this is delegated to the view model. You have a clean cut now between the UI that is responsible to display data and handle user input on the one hand, and state management on the other. The UI can be even developed independently of the rest of your app, it just needs a view model.

The view model is now responsible for delivering the *state* and handling the callbacks from the UI (the *events*). It is not concerned, however, how any of this is displayed. Since you didn't provide much about how your `DownloadManager` class works or how it is integrated in the app logic, the following will be more generic advice.

It would be best if `DownloadManager` could be refactored to provide `currentDownloads` as a `Flow<List<Download>>`. If you cannot change that code, though, the workaround would be to wrap a `callbackFlow` around `DownloadManager` and your listener implementation.

`callbackFlow` is actually used similar to `DisposableEffect`: Instead of `manager = downloadManager` in the listener implementation you would use any of the *send* methods (e.g. `trySendBlocking`), and instead of `onDispose` you would use `awaitClose`. If you use a layered architecture, all of this belongs in the data layer.

Finally, with the `Flow<List<Download>>` the following should be done in the view model:

1. Transform the list to a `DownloadsUiState`. That can be as easy as applying this to the flow:

   ```
    .map { DownloadsUiState(it) }
   ```

   If `Download` is unsuited to be exposed to your UI (because it isn't a simple data class and contains logic) you would need to transform this as well.
2. Transform the flow to a `StateFlow` so that only the latest value is used:

   ```
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = DownloadsUiState(emptyList()),
    )
   ```
3. Expose the flow to Compose by creating a property that contains the resulting flow. Steps 1 and 2 can be applied here as well, there are no intermediate variables necessary:

   ```
    val downloadsUiState: StateFlow<DownloadsUiState> = downloadflow
        .map { ... }
        .stateIn(...)
   ```

The flow is guaranteed to contain only the newest download data. Compose can simply collect this flow now with

```
val downloadsUiState by viewModel.downloadsUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

(You need the dependency `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose` in your build.gradle for this)

Your `LazyColumn` would then just take `downloadsUiState.downloads` instead of `manager.currentDownloads`.